# Python build script error

Tags: c++, python, g++, gsl

I am trying to compile a software using a python build script but I encounter the following error.

```
python build
[CC] cmd\threshold.o
 [CC] src\dwi/SH.o[CC] src\mrview/sidebar/orientation_plot.o

[CC] cmd\read_dicom.o
[CC] lib\file\dicom\dict.o
[CC] cmd\gen_unit_warp.o
[CC] cmd\mrinfo.o
 [CC] lib\file\dicom\image.o

 ERROR:
ERROR:  [CC] cmd\threshold.o[CC] src\dwi/SH.o



g++ -c -Wall -march=i686 -fno-strict-aliasing -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DUSE_TR1 -O
2 -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include -DGSL_DLL -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtkmm64/includ
e/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm64/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm64/include/sigc++-2.0
 -IC:/gtkmm64/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm64/
lib/glib-2.0/include -Ilib -Isrc cmd\threshold.cpp -o cmd\threshold.og++ -c -Wal
l -march=i686 -fno-strict-aliasing -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DUSE_TR1 -O2 -IC:/MinG
W/msys/1.0/local/include -DGSL_DLL -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtkmm64/include/glibmm-2.
4 -IC:/gtkmm64/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm64/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm
64/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm64/lib/glib-2.
0/include -Ilib -Isrc src\dwi/SH.cpp -o src\dwi/SH.o

failed with output:

In file included from lib/ptr.h:26:0,
                 from lib/args.h:26,
                 from lib/app.h:30,
                 from cmd\threshold.cpp:30:
lib/mrtrix.h:69:29: fatal error: gsl/gsl_version.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

the file it is looking for "gsl_version.h" is located in C:\GnuWin32\include\gsl and C:\GnuWin32\include is included in my path. So why do I get this error?

Much appreciated!!

Jesse

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see it as a `-IC:\GnuWin32\include` in the above command lines.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the g++ command is generated by the build script, they are not hard coded.

Comment: Try running the command by hand. Then add the switch I listed above to the command line and see if it changes the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error I had to add an environment variable LIB_GSL pointing to the gsl directory: C:\GnuWin32\include\gsl

cheers
Jesse